# Unable to boot device because it cannot be located on disk

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.1

The device's data is no longer present at */Users/[user name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D651BCC7-29FD-4B91-82F6-E255E856EA2F/data.*

I uninstalled xcode 9 and installed xcode 9.1, but when run project, following message was shown:

> Unable to boot device because it cannot be located on disk.
>   The device's data is no longer present at /Users/[user name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D651BCC7-29FD-4B91-82F6-E255E856EA2F/data.

I found "Developer" folder, but cannot find "CoreSimulator" folder.

Answer (score 569):

I was able to resolve the issue running `xcrun simctl erase all` in Terminal.

Comment: Accept this answer.

Comment: xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

Comment: you need to first run -> sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService

Comment: Before run `xcrun simctl erase all` in Terminal, Quit Xcode.app, Simulator.app. Otherwise, run script will fail.

Comment: God bless your soul :-)

Comment: @Milan Jansen ... save everyone and accept this answer :)

Comment: Oh man, that was scary! Yes, this answer needs to be accepted.

Comment: Work like a charm in 2023

Answer (score 61):

Quit Xcode.app, Simulator.app, etc

Try the following commands in Terminal

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService    
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```

Comment: still same error message, how do I add the simulators back?

Comment: I needed to run the killall command before I could use `xcrun simctl erase all` from above

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSS, finally! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
Ran all the above and then ran `xcrun simctl erase all`  and it started to work.

Comment: I tried the above and received errors in the terminal related to permissions even though I rand with sudo. I made sure I quite both Xcode and the simulator. I did a reboot and then it worked.

Comment: I think the cleanest way to stop a service is with launchctl, i.e. "launchctl stop com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService"

Answer (score 40):

Go to Xcode menu `Window`-> `Devices and Simulators` -> `Simulators` tab, right-click the bad simulator and choose `Delete` from the menu list, then add it back from the left bottom entry again, it works!

[image]

Comment: This worked for me thanks

Comment: This fixed it for me..

Answer (score 10):

Click on the simulators dropdown at the top of Xcode, and select `Download Simulators...`.

[image: Simulators Dropdown]

From here, you can select which versions you want to download and for what devices.

Comment: i dont' have a Download option

Answer (score 8):

Just run this command in terminal:

```
xcrun simctl shutdown all && xcrun simctl erase all
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2023

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue.**

It worked for me by erasing the device which your Mac does not found.

```
xcrun simctl erase AKADKJ-
```

Here is also a link where a found a good explanation.

https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc